# How do you prepend paths to a java class?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, gradlew

I'm building an older kafka (0.8.2.2) and am getting runtime errors about a missing java class:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/KafkaException`

When I look in libs/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar, I see the existence of kafka/common/KafkaException:

```
$ jar tf $CLASSPATH  | grep KafkaException
kafka/common/KafkaException.class
```

So it appears that the build (`gradlew jar`) constructed the class with the `org/apache` missing at the start of the class path.   How do I fix the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prepend paths to a Java class. The path must correspond to the package name. In your case the class `kafka.common.KafkaException` is found in libs/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar and `org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException` is found in libs/kafka-clients-0.8.2.2.jar.

You must include libs/kafka-clients-0.8.2.2.jar in your classpath as well.